# Finding $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{5^{1/x}}{2^{1/x^2}}$

Tags: limits

First I tried to make substitution $1/x=h$ and limit becomes

$$\lim\limits_{h\to \infty}\dfrac{5^{h}}{2^{h^2}}=\lim\limits_{h\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{5}{2^{h}}\right)^h$$

$2^h\to \infty$ so $5/2^h\to 0$ but also $5/2^h\to\infty$ in the same time.

Can you give me hint or how should I think general in $$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{a^{f(x)}}{b^{g(x)}}$$ cases

or can I use l hopital? I tried but got no solution like $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{5^{1/x}}{2^{1/x^2}}=[\infty/\infty]=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(\dfrac{5^{1/x}}{2^{1/x^2}}.x\dfrac{\ln5}{\ln2})$$

Comment: I assume that you actually mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}$ otherwise the substitution $1/x=h$ will give you $\lim_{h\rightarrow \pm \infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $h \rightarrow +\infty;$

$h \ge 4;$

$0<\frac{5^h}{2^{h^2}}=(\frac {5}{2^h})^h < (1/2)^h.$

2) $h \rightarrow -\infty:$

$h <-1;$

$0<\frac{5^h}{2^{h^2}}<(\frac{1}{5})\left (\frac{1}{2^{h^2}}\right)$;

Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

When $h >3$ we have $\frac 5 {2^{h}}<\frac 5 8$. Use the fact that $r^{h} \to 0$ as $h \to \infty$ if $|r|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{5}{2^h}$ tends to $0$ as $h\to \infty$, and we are further raising something tending to $0$ to an infinite power. That would make it *even* smaller. Any limit of the form $(\to 0)^{(\to \infty)}$ will always be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Determine  the limit of the log first:
$$\ln\biggl(\frac{5^{h}}{2^{h^2}}\biggr)=h\ln 5-h^2\ln 2.$$
This is a polynomial in $h$, and a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term  $-h^2\ln 2$, which tends to $-\infty$ as $h$ tends to $\infty$. Therefore, the fraction tends to $0$.